# Multi-platform support for binary data files with Extended type

Tags: floating-point, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I currently have the following code to support 10-bytes Extended values saved in binary files from Win32, and loading these in other platforms. However, for Android (which is ARM and not INTEL), I need some code to do conversion to and from 10-bytes IEEE format in 10-byte memory and the "Extended" type in the compiler (which is really an 8-byte Double).

```
TYPE
  TExtended     = TExtended80Rec;

{$IFDEF INTEL64 }
PROCEDURE ExtendedToIEEE(VAR D : Extended ; VAR E : TExtended); ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                FLD     QWORD PTR [RCX]
                FSTP    TBYTE PTR [RDX]
                FWAIT
  END;

PROCEDURE IEEEToExtended(CONST E : TExtended ; VAR D : Extended); ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                FLD     TBYTE PTR [RCX]
                FSTP    QWORD PTR [RDX]
                FWAIT
  END;
{$ELSE }
PROCEDURE ExtendedToIEEE(D : Extended ; VAR E : TExtended);
  BEGIN
    {$IF SizeOf(Extended)=SizeOf(TExtended) }
      MOVE(D,E,SizeOf(Extended))
    {$ELSE }
      !! MISSING !!
    {$ENDIF }
  END;

PROCEDURE IEEEToExtended(CONST E : TExtended ; VAR D : Extended);
  BEGIN
    {$IF SizeOf(Extended)=SizeOf(TExtended) }
      MOVE(E,D,SizeOf(Extended))
    {$ELSE }
      !! MISSING !!
    {$ENDIF }
  END;
{$ENDIF }
```

If possible, I'd also like to be able to convert to/from 16-bytes "Extended" type from MacOS/Linux (unless the 16-byte size is "just" an alignment, ie. 10-byte padded to 16).

Comment: If you are referring to the Intel “double extended-precision” floating-point format that uses 80 bits, that is an Intel format, not an IEEE format.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I am - I didn't know it wasn't IEEE format. I'll rename the functions in my code. But the question still stands :-)

Comment: `TExtendedHelper` in `SysUtils` contains all the logic you need. Basically you pull out the logic to extract sign, mantissa and exponent from an 80 bit value, and then feed those values back to `Double.BuildUp`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: But doesn't TExtendedHelper work on 8-byte Doubles in non-Extended targets?

Comment: I didn't say use it directly. I said pull the logic out of it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Thanks for the hint/tip - I have found a solution that doesn't involve me copying the entire record (type) helper, listed below...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the help of David above in the comments, I have come up with this, and provide it here for future reference:

```
TYPE
  TExtended     = TExtended80Rec;
  PExtended     = ^TExtended;

{$IF SizeOf(Extended)=SizeOf(TExtended) }
PROCEDURE ExtendedToIntel(VAR D : Extended ; VAR E : TExtended); INLINE;
  BEGIN
    D:=Extended(E)
  END;

PROCEDURE IntelToExtended(VAR E : TExtended ; VAR D : Extended); INLINE;
  BEGIN
    E:=TExtended(D)
  END;
{$ELSEIF DEFINED(WIN64) }
PROCEDURE ExtendedToIntel(VAR D : Extended {Double} ; VAR E : TExtended); ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                FLD     QWORD PTR [RCX]
                FSTP    TBYTE PTR [RDX]
                FWAIT
  END;

PROCEDURE IntelToExtended(VAR E : TExtended ; VAR D : Extended {Double} ); ASSEMBLER;
  ASM
                FLD     TBYTE PTR [RCX]
                FSTP    QWORD PTR [RDX]
                FWAIT
  END;
{$ELSE }
PROCEDURE ExtendedToIntel(D : Extended ; VAR E : TExtended);
  BEGIN
    PExtended(@E)^:=TExtended(D)
  END;

PROCEDURE IntelToExtended(CONST E : TExtended ; VAR D : Extended);
  BEGIN
    D:=Double(PExtended(@E)^)
  END;
{$ENDIF }

TYPE
  TStreamHelper = CLASS HELPER FOR TStream
                    FUNCTION ReadExtended : Extended;
                    PROCEDURE WriteExtended(E : Extended);
                  END;

{$IF SizeOf(Extended)=SizeOf(TExtended) }
FUNCTION TStreamHelper.ReadExtended : Extended;
  BEGIN
    Read(Result,SizeOf(Extended))
  END;

PROCEDURE TStreamHelper.WriteExtended(E : Extended);
  BEGIN
    Write(E,SizeOf(Extended))
  END;
{$ELSE }
FUNCTION TStreamHelper.ReadExtended : Extended;
  VAR
    EX  : TExtended;

  BEGIN
    Read(EX,SizeOf(TExtended));
    IntelToExtended(EX,Result)
  END;

PROCEDURE TStreamHelper.WriteExtended(E : Extended);
  VAR
    EX  : TExtended;

  BEGIN
    ExtendedToIntel(E,EX);
    Write(EX,SizeOf(EX))
  END;
{$ENDIF }
```

Comment: ExtendedToIntel in the else branch seems like it won't do anything useful. I'm also sceptical of using the x87 unit in win64. You don't know what state it will be in.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The ELSE branch is the whole "magic". It uses the implicit/explicit operator overload that Embarcadero already has that converts back and forth between 10 bytes and 8 bytes double format. All the other branches are just for compatibility (and speed in case of x64).

Comment: The function `ExtendedToIntel` in the `$ELSE` branch, accepts an arg named `D` which is never used. As for speed in x64, how do you know what state the x87 unit is in? Has it been initialised? What value does the CW have?

Comment: The CW has value $42, I assume. If not, you're on your own...
The D<->E was a typo, that has been corrected. Thanks for noticing...

Comment: Why do you think that it would have that value? On Win64 the Delphi RTL won't maintain the x87 control word. Why would it?

Comment: Because it's the ultimate answer... To Life, the Universe and Everything... :-)